# Use trackball for horizontal and vertical scrolling

Tags: ubuntu, x11, mouse, scrolling, xinput

I have a trackball mouse and want to extend the scrolling capabilities. Because the horizontal scrollwheel is very limited, I thought about using the trackball for scrolling when pressing a particular button as follows:

- Pressing the `back` (`xev` reports button 8) disables the trackball's mouse movement and remaps the horizontal/vertical trackball movement to horizontal/vertical scrolling (`xev` reports button 4 till 7 for scrolling).
- Releasing the `back` undoes the remapping

[Here is an example of a chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scrollbar-anywhere/namcaplenodjnggbfkbopdbfngponici/related?hl=de) which does exactly that, but I want to have this functionality systemwide.

I've investigated `xev` with no success regarding trackball movement and mapping. So my next idea is to investigate the `/dev/input/mouse` device and directly work with the trackball movement which seems to work. However, the two questions remain:

- How do I unmap and map the trackball movement with the mouse movement?
- Is there maybe an easier way to enable scrolling via trackball? (because writing an own program to capture mouse movements from `/dev/input/mouse` seems to be a bit overengineered.)

Comment: I would like to know as well, Have my Marble FX mouse from 1998 and I would like to use the red button on the side to 'activate' the scroll function with the big red ball.